# Prestashop CVSImport does not import my existing 17000 customers

Tags: prestashop, cvsimport

I try to import my existing customers to the new site which is prepared using prestashop. I prepared the cvs file as in the samples.I have over 17000 existing customer records.  When I tried to import whole file I managed to insert around 5000 records. I thought that maybe this number is too high for prestashop it causes some memory problems. 
Later I divided original file into smaller files which have 5000 records at most than I could import around 1500 records :) Later I tried file with 1000 records result was even smaller.

In the end I tried file with 200 records at most and I could import around 87 using cvsimport. This is meaningless. Everytime I clear the table before cvsimport... I don't get an error. It looks like import finishes correctly but when I check the # of records I see the bad result....

Is this a known issue? How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also inserted the customers usind sql script. I utilized excel to prepare the sql scripts. First I divided my data to 17 different tabs later I prepared sql for 1000 records at most. Even if I enter data with sql script I had problem with data bigger than 1000 records.

This is a sample sql

INSERT INTO `ps_customer`(`active`, `id_gender`,  `email`,`passwd`, `lastname`, `firstname`, `newsletter`,`optin`) VALUES 
(1,9, "email@yahoo.com",  MD5(CONCAT('cookiekeycookiekeycookiekey','password')),"surname","name",1,1);

Later you should run the script below otherwise you can not login

INSERT INTO `ps_customer_group` (id_customer,id_group) SELECT id_customer,3 FROM ps_customer WHERE id_customer NOT IN (SELECT id_customer FROM `ps_customer_group`)

In my existing data I had the address in the same table but in prestashop adres is stored in another table. I prepared the sql below to use the customerid s in address table.

INSERT INTO `ps_address`(`id_customer`, `id_country`, `id_state`, `alias`, `company`, `lastname`, `firstname`, `address1`, `postcode`, `city`, `phone`, `phone_mobile`, `vat_number`) VALUES
    ((  SELECT `id_customer`  FROM `ps_customer` WHERE `email` = "email@hotmail.com"    ),  211 ,   0   , " Adres1  ","     "," Surname "," Name    ","Adress details ","   10000   "," İstanbul    "," tel1    "," mobile tel  ","     "));

That all ...

Ferda

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar problem with others entities. CVSImport in Prestashop have more errors.

You have two options:

```
   Option A: Generate an sql script and upload data via mysql. In this case, you can use msexcel or similar for create a formula and generate sql sentences for test this option.

   Option B: Try with webservice prestashop. This option I have not been able to use.
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I had almost same problem for my products(3000), the UPDATE failed (memory exeded) due to my tiny hosting plan.

To make the CSV upload work, i had to clone my Prestashop in local( under WAMP )

Did the import in local, once it was finish i just copied the TABLEs from my local bdd to my distant bdd

good luck